# Parse error while installing application

Tags: android

Am new to android studio.When I build and run the application everything seems to be fine.But am getting parse error while installing the app.
referred other posts,but didn't help

This is my build.gradle file

```
<apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion '20.0.0'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.xxxx"
        minSdkVersion 8
        targetSdkVersion 21
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    productFlavors {
    }
}
dependencies {
    compile files('libs/google-play-services.jar')
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.0.1'
    compile files('libs/ksoap2-android-2.5.2.jar')
}
```

manifest file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="xxxx" >

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
    <uses-sdk android:maxSdkVersion="21" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
       >
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"           />
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
            android:value="@string/google_maps_key" />

        <activity
            android:name="Activity"
            android:label="activity_maps" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: In your original post, the manifest file starts with `<<?`. Is that *actually* what's in your file? Additionally, please post the *exact* error message you're getting - and avoid posting anything in all-caps, as it's considered to be shouting.

Answer (score 0):

It seems your first statement is corrupt. Remove the first character in your build.gradle script. Instead of

```
<apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
```

write

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
```

Comment: No,it's like that,no tags

Comment: I didn't get it what you said. Please post the error trace.

Comment: problm is not that Thomas,I hv written code as you said

Comment: 'There is a problem parsing the package'.this is the error msh while installing the application